# Docusign API Verification: What is Response Trace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, response, docusignapi

My app has Docusign fully built in finally. I'm wrapping up the documentation I need to get it approved, but I'm confused by what they mean when they ask for the full response trace. Would this be the response that I get after making my API call? Or is it the request that I send out.

*The Trace must be a raw, fully consumable request and response including headers. DocuSign should be able to recreate the event using 
the provided trace. We are looking for the verb/method, URI, endpoint, authentication method, credentials, and payload. The intent is to 
validate that your Support teams can provide this information when contacting DocuSign Support for backend assistance.*

-[Docusign Source](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/API_Certification20130522.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're looking for you to demonstrate your ability to produce a full trace of both **Request** and **Response** for an API call that your application makes.  For example, if my application made a "Create Envelope" call, then my trace of the **Request** might look something like this:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/201105/envelopes HTTP/1.1

Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 568
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"USER_NAME","Password":"PASSWORD","IntegratorKey":"INTEGRATOR_KEY"}
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6

{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this",
  "emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
  "templateId": "3C9D42D3-3E76-4669-861E-9670415E1AD3",
  "templateRoles": [
   {
      "roleName": "Signer1",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": "123",
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

And my trace of the (successful) **Response** would look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 195
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 19:06:05 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains

{
  "envelopeId": "aab13a9d-c4f7-4d95-b31c-11eed676cbc5",
  "uri": "/envelopes/aab13a9d-c4f7-4d95-b31c-11eed676cbc5",
  "statusDateTime": "2013-11-26T19:06:05.4064392Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Notice that the traces include all information -- i.e., Request trace includes the VERB, the URI, all headers, and request body; Response trace includes headers and response body.  You can easily generate request/response traces like this using a tool like **Fiddler** or something similar.

Basically, DocuSign wants you to demonstrate that you're able to produce the Request and Response trace for an API call, because if you ever have API issues down the road and need to contact DocuSign Support for assistance, the first thing they're going to ask you for is a full trace of Request and Response for the problematic API call(s). By ensuring, as part of the API Certification process, that you're able to produce Request/Response traces for your integration, they're ensuring that you'll be able to provide DocuSign Support with the information they need to troubleshoot your issues if/when that time ever comes.

Answer (score 1):

To get api trace log you need to follow this page-

> https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

and go to

> https://app2.docusign.com/preferences/security

and enable and click api logs which provide several zip file containing .txt files.